# Problem importing module for GRAPHENE setting 'SCHEMA' in Django 2.2

Tags: python, django, graphql

I am new to django(installed version 2.2 in my virtualenv) and graphql. I tried to follow the instructions for setting up graphql in django from the following site

https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/installation/

When I try to run the server with the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/

I get the following error.

```
ImportError at /graphql/
Could not import 'django_root.schema.schema' for Graphene setting 
'SCHEMA'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_root'.
```

I followed the instructions carefully but I am unable to get this right. Please help. I checked similar questions but it didn't help.

Edit: 
I tried the following

`'SCHEMA': 'folder_with_setting.py_file.schema.schema'`

`'SCHEMA': 'folder_with_manage.py_file.schema.schema'`

`'SCHEMA': 'folder_with_manage.py_file.folder_with_settings.py_file.schema.schema'`

`'SCHEMA': 'folder_with_manage.py_file/folder_with_settings.py_file.schema.schema'`

and many other combinations. It's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the right path of your project in settings.py

```
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'django_root.schema.schema'  #  change your path
}
```

Where path.schema.schema is the location of the Schema object in your Django project.

Comment: should I put the "os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))" like I have with BASE_DIR  in the settings.py ?

Comment: just try absolute path or relative path first

Comment: Ok, should I point to the file schema.py or just the folder ?

Answer (score 2):

```
'SCHEMA': 'addyourappnamehere.schema.schema',
```

faced the same error
this worked
i added the app name
eg:

```
'SCHEMA': 'auth.schema.schema',
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have to address the path where your `schema.py` is located. For example, the app name in which you have looks like the following project outline:

```
django_project
├── app_name
│   ├── model.py
│   ├── schema.py
│   └── ...
├── django_project
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── ...
└── ...
```

Now into the `settings.py` add the following lines:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'app_name',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles', # Required for GraphiQL
    'graphene_django',
)

GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'app_name.schema.schema' # Where your Graphene schema lives
}
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

You can also follow [this instruction](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-plain/) step by step.